# how to configure per-vlan traffic shaping on catalyst 3560?

Tags: vlan, cisco-catalyst

I have successfully configured VLANs and inter-VLAN routing. Now I want to be able to apply bandwidth limits to each VLAN, especially ingress (into the switch towards gateway) but possibly also egress (out of the switch from gateway).

I don't want to classify/prioritize the traffic for now; it should be the same rule for all packets on a particular VLAN.

The official documentation on this is quite a long read: https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/switches/lan/catalyst3560/software/release/15-0_2_se/configuration/guide/scg3560/swqos.html#32758. I'm having trouble understanding which bits apply to my situation.

Can someone please post an example that I can get started with?